# iOS7 xCode 5 - Date Picker selection output to Label

Tags: xcode, ios7, datepicker, label

I've seen a few other questions similar to this but they all seem to have varying solutions and none of them work. 
I'm only just figuring out this whole xcode thing, so if you wouldn't mind keeping it fairly explanatory and easy to follow that would be absolutely great and most appreciated!

I have a date picker (with date and time showing) and a label in my view, and I'd like the label to display the current selection of the date picker, updating every time the date picker is adjusted, in the format as the following example:

Sunday 9th February 2014 14:00

At the moment, I can only seem to get the label to output the current date, which is odd?

Also, I'd like to set the picker so that users can only choose a date and time in the future, nothing from the past!

Many thanks for any help, really appreciate all of you guys sharing the knowledge :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are a few questions asked, so I will answer them accordingly in the comments:

> 1. I'd like the label to display the current selection of the date picker
> 2. updating every time the date picker is adjusted
> 3. in the format as the following, Sunday 9th February 2014 14:00
> 4. set the picker so that users can only choose a date and time in the future, nothing from the past!

```
//declared as a property
UIDatePicker *dateTimePicker; 
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;
UILabel *lblDateDisplay;
NSDate *selectedDate;

//in your viewdidload
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateTimePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 220)]; //whatever you want it, I am just listing an example
[dateTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];
[dateTimePicker setHidden:NO];
[dateTimePicker setDate:[NSDate date]]; 
[dateTimePicker setMinimumDate: [NSDate date]]; //no.4
[dateTimePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChangedValue) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; //no.2

//create another method called, dateChangedValue
- (void) dateFromChangedValue { 
  selectedDate = dateTimePicker.date;
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMM YYYY HH:mm"]; //no.3
  lblDateDisplay.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate]; //no.1
}
```

There, I am done. I guess you could try these codes.